# Is this polynomial irreducible? $f(x)=x^3-117x+53$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials, cubics

I am trying to find if  $f(x)=x^3-117x+53$ is irreducible or reducible.

I tried Eisenstein's criterion but this fails as $53$ does not divide $117$

After some thinking, if f(x) has any roots then they will be negative, but I have had no luck finding any.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks

Comment: It is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, but not $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @vadim123 thanks for the reply. Why is it irreducible over Q?

Comment: For irreducibility over say the rationals, use the Rational Roots Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cubic (or quadratic) with rational coefficients is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if it has no rational roots.

By the [Rational Roots Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) the only candidates for rational roots of our cubic are $\pm 1$ and $\pm 53$. None of them works.

We conclude that our cubic is irreducible over the rationals, and as a consequence irreducible over the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation modulo $5$.

$x^3-2x+3\pmod{5}$

When $x\equiv 0\pmod{5}$, the above equates to $3\pmod{5}$

When $x\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, the above equates to $2\pmod{5}$

When $x\equiv 2\pmod{5}$, the above equates to $4\pmod{5}$

When $x\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, the above equates to $4\pmod{5}$

When $x\equiv 4\pmod{5}$, the above equates to $4\pmod{5}$

Since the integers can be partitioned into the classes modulo $5$ and we see that no class could possibly be a root, we know there are no integer roots and it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since a monic polynomial whose coefficients are all integers will be irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29), we see that it is irreducible.